# Code coverage during manual testing in .NET development server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, testing, code-coverage, manual-testing

I have an application hosted in development server.

I need to determine the code coverage at the time of manual testing done by QA guys. Thus I am able to find out that how much code have been covered by QA.

Thanks in advance to all.

Is there any third party tool which can help me to do this. I have used dotCover, but that can only cover the local IIS application, not remotely hosted application.

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**NCover** is a .Net tool for code coverage checking for .Net programs. You can use its latest version for both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. This tool can perform manual as well as automated code coverage tests for .Net programs. Using NCover may speed up your tests, providing you with nice and attractive multiple testing environments.
Key Features: supports statement coverage and branch coverage, very fast tool, simple to use, provides better code quality, supports 32 & 64-bit OS, auto upgrade and update notifications for new service
License: Floating License
Latest Version: NCover 4.5.2745.646
Tool for: .Net programs
Download NCover

**Emma** is a free and open source code coverage tool. Emma checks and reports for code coverage in a source code of a Java program. Emma can check code coverage for: class, method, line, package, etc. This code coverage tool is purely for Java programs. Among popular code coverage tools, it is a preferred choice of many users.
Key Features: fast tool, good for large scale software development projects, ability to detect partially created source code line for code coverage, provide reports in plain text, HTML, and XML formats
Developer(s): Vlad Roubtsov
License: Common Public License
Latest Version: Emma 2.1
Tool for: Java programs
Platform Supported: Cross Platform
Download Emma

**OpenCover** is a free and open source tool for code coverage checking for .Net programs. It checks for code coverage of tests in minimum time. OpenCover acquires less memory and can generate nice HTML, XML coverage reports. It is one of the best code coverage tools for generating nice output reports.
Key Features: supports Silverlight, supports 32 & 64-bit OS, supports statement coverage and branch coverage, excellent coverage reports generation
License: MIT Licence
Latest Version: OpenCover 4.5.3207
Tool for: .Net programs
Download NCover

And some tools like

1. Jester
2. JVMDI Code Coverage Analyser
3. PIT

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Any of the above tools can do the code coverage for remotely hosted application. Such as, for any LIVE application?